# An error occurs when using the pgsql cache

Tags: ruby, postgresql

There is a script like this in Ruby

```
def self.cached_count
    @cached_count ||= begin
      table = Arel::Table.new(:pg_class)
      query = table.project(table['reltuples']).where(table['relname'].eq('receipts')).to_sql
      result = connection.exec_query query
      result&.first&.[]('reltuples')&.to_i
    end
    cach_count = ReceiptsCashe.where('id > ?', self.last.id).count
    page = cach_count % self.per_page > 0 ? 1 : 0
    @cached_count += ( cach_count / self.per_page).to_i + page
    @cached_count
  end
```

This takes the page count to display the data in the table with the page output in rails. The problem is that the cache lags behind the actual data. The size of the table is about 500 million records. I made an additional table where new records are put via after_create for the model. And from this data the final counter size is generated. But the problem is that this approach doesn't work well either, there is always new data that doesn't make it to the output page. I have this question, how can I quickly get the last record from a big table, its id or creation date, so that the page count for the table is always up to date.

Comment: I would suggest invalidating the cache whenever you add new records to the table.

Comment: [Don't try to display an exact result set count.](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/#total-count)